# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION while activating System Extension

Tags: objective-c, macos, system, macos-catalina

following is the code i am using to activate system extension on macos catalina

```
{
    OSSystemExtensionRequest *SysReq = [[OSSystemExtensionRequest alloc] init];
    [OSSystemExtensionRequest activationRequestForExtension:SysReq.identifier queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    SysReq.delegate = RequestDelegate;
    [OSSystemExtensionManager.sharedManager submitRequest:SysReq];

}
```

but after i reach the end of the current function i get an exception.
following are the details ---

**Thread 4: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

**Thread 4 Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)**

## 0  0x00007fff49aa734a in -[OSSystemExtensionRequest failedWithError:] ()

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `bundleId` as `NSString`.

```
[OSSystemExtensionRequest activationRequestForExtension:@"yourOrg.name.appname"
                                        queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

And make sure your entire code is on a  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^() {...`